# Building a project with Groovy extension methods in it

Tags: gradle, groovy

I'm trying to build a simple Groovy project which contains a package with a Groovy extension method.

When I try to compile the project the classes using the extension method can't find it. The descriptor and the class are picked up correctly by the IDE.

I guess the problem is that the extension method is needed at compile time by which it probably hasn't been compiled yet.
I've tried creating different sourceSets but with no success.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.4.7'
    compile 'org.membrane-soa:service-proxy-core:4.2.2'
    testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4'
    extensionCompile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.4.7'
}

sourceSets {
    extension {
        groovy {
            include '**/ClosureExtension.groovy'
        }
    }
    main {
        groovy {
            compileClasspath += extension.output
        }
    }
}
```

The extension method lives in src/main/groovy/com/predic8/membrane/dsl/extension and the rest of the project in src/main/groovy/com/predic8/membrane/dsl/.

P.S.: The project classes are all annotated with @CompileStatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach: separate the extension code into its own project, and produce a jar from that project. Then, in another project, the DSL code can use that jar and specify the extension jar *as a dependency*.

This would make a huge answer, so I mocked it up and placed it on GitHub [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_gradle/tree/master/egg_Extension_Method) (with all due credit to [mrhaki's post](http://mrhaki.blogspot.ca/2013/01/groovy-goodness-adding-extra-methods.html)). There are two projects: `extension` and `dsl`. Assuming you understand multi-project builds in Gradle, the essence is this line from `dsl/build.gradle`:

```
compileGroovy.dependsOn tasks.getByPath(':extension:jar')
```